# Degradation issues for HTML5 semantic tags (article, footer, header)

Tags: html, cross-browser

How well do the new layout tags in HTML5 degrade? What are the hazards in using them? (I'm not talking about `<video>`--I've seen specific fallback code for it).

Specifically, in the case of something like

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Talking Dogs</h1>
<b><p>Humans aren't the only talkers!</p></b>
</header>
<article>
<p>Ever encountered a talking dog? I have.</p>
<p>It all happened one day as I was walking down the street...</p>
</article>
<footer>
© 2009 Woofer Dog Corporation
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Would using `<header>`, `<article>`, or `<footer>` cause any browser problems? Do they degrade to `<div>` in unsupporting browsers automatically? Or if I include them, should I only include them for semantic meaning, and not for CSS styling or DOM scripting?

Comment: (Code taken from http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_footer_tag.cfm)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As long as you use [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to handle IE, it will work fine.

The browser will treat all unknown tags (including HTML5 tags) as normal inline elements.
You should include the following CSS rule:

```
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section { display: block; }
```

Comment: But then there's the problem of whether the user has JavaScript enabled or not...

Comment: @new: IE users are not likely to disable Javascript (except for ESC).

Comment: If a person uses IE on purpose and has javascript disabled on purpose, their subpar internet experience is their own fault. It's like turning off your monitor and expecting to still be able to see your mouse cursor.

Comment: Normalize.css will do this for you - just as an fyi

Answer (score 1):

For presentation you'll use CSS anyhow, so doesn't really matter if browser understands the tag itself.

Comment: so, if I style 
footer { display:block; background-color: pink;}
it'll work across browsers, even ones that don't really know what footer is?

Comment: "not knowing the tag" basically means "not knowing how to display tag by default", if you override that with custom CSS, they browser will know how to display. Note, that CSS works even with XML, where you can have totally custom tags.

Comment: Yes, it will work, as long as you add http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js

Comment: you need to create the elements otherwise IE won't style them

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 Tags are not supported in IE the tags are still inactive. To activate the semantic HTML5 tags in IE use the following script inside your head section.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
var html5elmeents = "address|article|aside|audio|canvas|command|datalist|details|dialog|figure|figcaption|footer|header|hgroup|keygen|mark|meter|menu|nav|progress|ruby|section|time|video".split('|');
for(var i = 0; i < html5elmeents.length; i++){
document.createElement(html5elmeents[i]);
}
}
)();
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Tested, and it works (IE9/Win7).  Question:  What are the advantages of this script over html5shiv?

Comment: @james.garriss IE9+ supports the semantic tags without this JavaScript hack. This code is for IE8 and below. To answer your question, the HTML5shiv and this do exactly the same thing - 'create' the elements using the createElement argument. With JS disabled, this won't happen, but JS is almost relied upon these days.