# What’s a good HTML library for ASP.NET that supports replacing HTML5 tags with backwards-compatible equivalents?

Tags: asp.net, html, cross-browser

I've been running a regex string.replace for a while to change the HTML output for older browsers, replacing HTML specific tags with span/div tags via an HttpModule. Since IE6-8 won't recognize tags such as article, footer and so on.

But when trying to fix a bug in the regex pattern (and posting about it here) I found out that it's really NOT a good way to go about it, regex is not an HTML parser. [(Read a great article by Jeff Atwood about it)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Since there's still a bug in my regex I'm starting to look for an alternate solution for the problem. I've used [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and I works great. But my problem is that some of the users of the application I'm building can't use JS and I still want the markup in HTML5 (for video mostly).

Have anyone done this without JS and regex? I've been looking for a HTML parser but haven't found one where I can replace tag names.

Comment: You shouldn't need to go through all that effort. Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967286/degradation-issues-for-html5-semantic-tags-article-footer-header/2967324#2967324) for details.

Comment: @jnpcl: read the question — it says “without JS”. html5shiv is JavaScript.

Comment: @Paul: Yeah, my bad. I stopped reading when he talked about parsing HTML with RegEx.

Comment: @jnpcl: heh! Can’t blame you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)? That seems to be the de facto .NET library for manipulating HTML.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at it! Do you know if it supports renaming tags? The documentation is a windows help-file and I use mac at home :D

Comment: @fredrik Probably, but if not you can definitely remove an `HtmlNode` and replace it with a different one. The documentation is horrible anyway - the best documentation is on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack). Who needs documentation when you're a jedi code ninja? You *are* a jedi code ninja, right?

Comment: Ended up using Html Agility Pack. :)

Answer (score 2):

The two reasonably well known .NET parsers for HTML are the HTML Agility Pack and [SGMLReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/SgmlReader). I've not used either in anger, so can't offer any detailed advice on them.

The result of a parser however, is typically a DOM, and the DOM API does not provide a means to change the name of an element. So in each case where you want to convert, you'll need to:

- Create a new div or span element
- move the attributes from the HTML5 element to the new one
- add any appropriate class name that you want to the class attribute (e.g. 'footer' or 'article')
- move the child nodes of the HTML5 element to be children of the new one (preserving order)
- replace the HTML5 element in its parent with the new element.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with ASP.NET and C#, but you might want to look at XML libraries — they might accept your HTML5 as input even if it’s not strictly XML, and allow you to do the tag replacement you want.