# is it ok to use server-side browser detection to ensure graceful degradation of html5 semantic tags in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, cross-browser, browser-detection

It is a well known fact that [html5 semantic tags won't degrade gracefully in IE lesser than version 9 without some help in form of conditional javascript snippet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967286/degradation-issues-for-html5-semantic-tags-article-footer-header)  It means that users with IE7 and turned off javascript will see something ugly instead of your shiny html5 site.

I thought of the way to address that, and came up with the following approach: on the server side (say in mvc view) have something in lines of:

```
    OutputHtml5WithFallback("<header>MyHeader</header>", "<div>MyHeader</div>");
```

and have a browser sniffing code to figure out if the request came from IE7 or IE8. If the browser is recognized as IE7 or IE8, html output will be

```
    <div>MyHeader</div>
```

otherwise

```
    <header>MyHeader</header>
```

It seems to be kind of spoofing-proof - if any browser pretends to be IE7 it will receive html5 markup without any html5 elements. My biggest concern is that this approach may be discouraged by search engines (since the different html is served for different User Agents).

Could you point out other flaws that I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to careful about proxy caching, otherwise a proxy may cache your IE7 page and serve it to more modern browsers, or cache your HTML5 page and serve it to IE7 and your server will never get an opportunity to supply the correct version.

Unless your site already requires that your HTML pages not be cached, whatever you do to avoid this problem will increase the load on your server.

Comment: good point, thanks. I don't think I will be disabling the caching to be able to serve different html markup to IE7.

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** See bfrohs comment. You *do* still have to use `document.createElement('HTML5ElementName')` in order to get proper styling after all.

Nonetheless I don't think going to server-side lengths to shim in HTML5 degradation is a good idea. If someone is still using IE6/7/8 and has JavaScript disabled by default, the vast majority of pages online (from Facebook to the New York Times) won't be functional to them *anyway.*

---

In HTML, unknown elements (like `<blah>`) are automatically considered inline elements. To correct for older versions of IE, you need to set all of the new block-level elements to `display: block;`, which is what the CSS does:

```
article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary { 
    display:block;
}
```

This solves 99% of the layout problems with HTML5 on older browsers. (Others such as audio and video with controls may still need work or a different fallback mechanism to be actually useful)

Comment: could you explain in more details how CSS alone will work? The webpage you linked specifically says 'include javascript' in 'how to use' section. And they use $.webshims.polyfill(); to initialize.

Comment: CSS alone will *not* work. Older IEs don't parse the same way, resulting in a mangled DOM. See http://blog.whatwg.org/supporting-new-elements-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

As long as your styling does not depend on the new HTML5 elements you can view an HTML5 in IE7 without problems.

So you could use:

```
<header><div class="header"></div></header>
```

It's not very beautiful, but it would save you from serverside code.