# Are there any downsides to using html5 semantic tags over traditional divs?

Tags: css, html, browser, compatibility

[The inverse question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272019/why-to-use-html5-semantic-tag-instead-of-div) [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822024/are-new-html5-elements-like-section-and-article-pointless) [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305723/why-use-html5-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097957/what-is-the-difference-between-nav-and-div?noredirect=1&lq=1). However I could neither find any cons nor convincing proof of their complete absence.

I am all for progress and semantic documents. In fact I have started to use new semantic tags in my markups already a while ago (it feels nice!). Still I wonder if there are any (possibly obscure) caveats one should know about.

- Will the rendering break (more) on that office machine which rolls prehistoric versions of IE?
- backwards compatibility of css selectors like `article`?
- strange side effects to the DOM?
- ...(*anything*)?

Comment: I eventually found this quite old question which mostly matches what I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2967324/5616681

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some older browsers don't recognize the html5 elements. At best this means you have to define default style rules for those elements in your CSS.

In some cases you might need to apply a shim, or in this case, a shiv:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/make-html5-elements-work-in-old-ie/

Again, old browsers (I'm looking at you, IE) won't even recognize them as elements, so yes, it would likely change the structure of your DOM. Also, I've seen old browsers just output the html5 tags as plain text, so you see the `<article>` tag right there in your content.

---

If you happen to be in a situation where you can't support the new html5 elements, one handy workaround is to use divs and give them classes that match the desired element names. So for example you'd use:

`<div class="article">`
instead of
`<article>`

This approach has the benefit of sticking to the new "mental model", you can still think of your content in terms of articles and asides or whatnot. This approach also has the benefit of making it relatively straightforward to upgrade your code to full html5 spec at some point in the future, as all you have to do is search for the classes and replace the divs as appropriate.